# Add missing import statements from another code

Tags: java, string

I have 2 strings(**string1** & **string2**) which contains the code of 2 java classes.

**string1** contains :-

```
    package com.test.package;

    import com.abc.Test1;
    import com.abc.Test2;
    import com.abc.Test2.Test21;
    import com.abc.Test10;

    public class TestA {
        public void testMethod(){
           //Method body
        }
    }
```

**string2** contains :-

```
    package com.test.package;

    import com.abc.Test1;
    import com.abc.Test2;
    import com.abc.Test3;
    import com.def.ghi.Test4;
    import com.def.ghi.Test5;

    public class TestB {
        public void testMethod(){
           //Method body
        }
    }
```

Now what I need is I need to copy all the import statements which are not in **string1** from **string2**.

Expected :-

```
    package com.test.package;

    import com.abc.Test1;
    import com.abc.Test2;
    import com.abc.Test2.Test21;
    import com.abc.Test10;
    import com.abc.Test3;
    import com.def.ghi.Test4;
    import com.def.ghi.Test5;

    public class TestA {
        public void testMethod(){
           //Method body
        }
    }
```

Can anybody please help me to solve this scenario (atleast to get the missing import statements)?

Comment: `package` can't be used as identifier.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show us some code? I would basically read the lines of each file into separate lists, remove those that don't start with `"import"` and then compare...

Comment: Yes @deHaar , What I am thinking is to take the import statements in string2 as a list and check whether it is in string1 or not. If it is not there just copy those imports in string1.
But my doupt is how will I take all the import statements from string2 in a list.

Comment: How are you trying to read the files? Can you show that code? Do you use `java.io` or `java.nio`?

Comment: @deHaar Using java.io. What's the point in knowing how it read the files ? I already got the file contents as strings. I just need to get the import statements from string2 which are not in string1.

Comment: **1.** Read all `import` statements from `string1` line by line. I assume each import statement is on its own line, otherwise you would need something like a Java parser. **2.** Put them in a `Set`. **3.** Read all `import` statements from `string2`. **4.** Put them in a `Set`. **5.** Add the second set to the first set, using `addAll`.

Comment: @MCEmperor Thanks. I have confusion in how I get all the import statements. I can take the first import statement using string1.indexOf("import"). But how will I take the last import ?

Comment: @Anas Read what MC Emperor wrote.  He said "read all import statements from string1 **line by line**.  You should end up with a List of lines, each import statement i a separate string.  Don't read the whole file into a single string, that's too complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow below steps :

1.First you need to split string into string array and take out import as a string.

```
String[] string1Array = string1.split("\n\n");
result : string1Array[0]=package com.test.package;
         string1Array[1]=import com.abc.Test1;
                         import com.abc.Test2;
                         import com.abc.Test2.Test21;
                         import com.abc.Test10;
String[] string2Array = string2.split("\n\n");
```

2. Now you have to split import statements.

> ```
> String[] importStringArray1 = string1Array[1].split("\n");
> String[] importStringArray2 = string2Array[1].split("\n");
> output : importStringArray1[0]=import com.abc.Test1;
>              importStringArray1[1]=import com.abc.Test2;
>              importStringArray1[2]=import com.abc.Test2.Test21;
> ```

3. Now you have to check that import in string2 is available or not in string 1. If its not present than add into string1.

   ```
   string1 =  string1Array[0].concat("\n\n");
   string1 = string1.concat(string1Array[1]);
   for(String a : importStringArray2) {
         boolean found = false;
         for(String b : importStringArray1){
            if(a.queals(b)) {
               found=true;break;
            }
         }
         if(!found){
            string1=string1.concat("\n").concat(a);
         }
   }
   string1=string1.concat("\n\n").concat(string1Array[2]);
   ```

Hope, This will work!